# Ordinal logistic regression with interaction

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, likert

I have a dependent variable donation intention on a 7-point likert scale(1=totally disagree, 7= totally agree), an independent variable which is a dummy (0= price is not framed, 1 = price is framed) and three moderating variables which are prior exposure to payment on a 7-point likert scale (1 = none, 7 = all), hourly salary (continuous number), annual income (These income classes start from less than 10.000€ and then add up by 10.000€ each class until 50.000€ where 50.000€ is added to 100.000€. The second last class is 100.000€ until 200.000€, and the last class is 200.000€ or more).

I want to measure the interaction effects of the moderators on the relationship between the condition and the donation intention all separately, so 3 different analyses (per moderator one analysis). I'm not sure which analysis to use. I think ordinal logistic regression but I'm not sure. Does anyone maybe also have a tip on how to do this in R studio?

Comment: It sounds like ordinal regression will be a good approach.  In R, the *ordinal* package can fit these models and post-hoc comparisons can be performed with the *emmeans* package.  ...  There is always a question about how to handle ordinal variables on the right-hand side of the model.  I have a brief comment about it here: [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/573926/how-to-consider-categorial-ordinal-variable#comment1059507_573926](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/573926/how-to-consider-categorial-ordinal-variable#comment1059507_573926)

Comment: I now conducted a moderated linear multiple regression. Do you think it is crucial to change this to ordinal logistic regression or should it be fine like that? I changed all my variables to numeric variables for that, even the annual income categories and likert scales

Comment: If your data reasonably meet the assumptions of linear regression, then you are probably fine.  Really, it is up to you if you think that it is reasonable to treat your 7-point Likert scale (or *item* ?) as numeric.  For your own edification, you might refit the model with ordinal regression and see if it makes any difference.